# Authenticate against a remote system in Eclipse using GSSAPI

Tags: eclipse, single-sign-on, remote-server, gssapi

When I'm trying to connect to a remote system in Eclipse using GSSAPI, Eclipse asks me for the active directory user's password.

[image]

I know that there are configurations in Eclipse "Preferences" -> "Network Connection" -> "SSH2" -> "Authentication Methods". I tried it with the selection of all enabled (gssapi-with-mic, publickey, password, keyboard-interactive) and just "gssapi-with-mic". It still prompts for the password. I don't know if it even tries to authenticate using gssapi or if it always skips it. Unfortunately, the "Diagnose Connection Problems..." option of Eclipse doesn't include information about it.

I tried the connection with PuTTY and WinSCP in order to enclose the problem. Both Tools were able to connect to the remote system successfully using gssapi. So the problem is located in Eclipse (configuration).
Are there other settings regarding gssapi which I should take into consideration in Eclipse? Can someone approve that he or she is able to use gssapi with Eclipse?

Thank you for any help! :)

Comment: JGSS isn't using the native Kerberos ticket cache via SSPI, but rather JGSS.

Comment: Thank you, this could actually have been the cause. Unfortunately, I currently no longer have access to the infrastructure to test it.